# Pagination shows extra item when at start or end of items

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

My pagination component is showing an extra, undesired item when the user is at or near either the beginning or the end of the item list. I believe I am matching my props exactly to what I am inputting in the documentation 'options' example, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

[Current behavior GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM2Oi.jpg)

[Desired behavior GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvVR7.jpg)

```
class MyPagination extends React.Component<PaginationProps> {
  static defaultProps = {
    boundaryRange: 0,
    defaultActivePage: 1,
    showEllipsis: false,
    siblingRange: 2,
  };

  render() {
    const {
      boundaryRange,
      defaultActivePage,
      showEllipsis,
      siblingRange,
      totalPages,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <Pagination
        boundaryRange={boundaryRange}
        defaultActivePage={defaultActivePage}
        ellipsisItem={showEllipsis ? undefined : null}
        siblingRange={siblingRange}
        totalPages={totalPages}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyPagination;
```

I'm instantiating like this:

```
<MyPagination totalPages={50} />
```

And my props are coming out as expected:

[image: React Dev Tools screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is a bug and was fixed in `semantic-ui-react@0.84.0` by https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/3271.